# IE <= 11 Not liking toString.call(value)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, internet-explorer

When I attempt to run

```
function isRegExp(value) { 
  return toString.call(value) === '[object RegExp]'; 
}
```

in IE <= 11 (tried on 11 and 9), I get a `TypeError: Invalid calling object`. This code works in newer versions as well as other browsers.

Firstly, I am confused. This function is identical to the [AngularJS function](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/14ff529fbbff46413c0cb451a2f0abbd16b05d5e/src/Angular.js#L542), and Angular claims to support IE 9+. How is it that the same line of code, when I use it, causes an error (and thus causes my calling function to break), when I assume they have tested it already?

Secondly, I am curious about what exactly could be causing the issue. This value can be anything in Javascript, and it only seems to be breaking with some of the things I send it (it doesn't seem to break when just given a simple array, but seems to struggle with arrays of objects of arrays of objects...ect.)

Comment: Why would you do this? If you want to know whether the input is a RegExp object, why aren't you just literally doing that by using `function isRegExp(v) { return v instanceof RegExp; }`? (If you'd never seen `instanceof` before: that's a thing. It's been a JavaScript feature since ECMAScript 1 =)

Comment: To be honest, I am just using exactly what the guys who made AngularJS are doing. I imagine there must be some sort of reason they did this and not what you suggested?

Comment: being overly complicated? If you have no idea why you're doing something that "very clever people" did, do it the easier way until that's an actual problem.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans: This is a common mechanism for getting the type of an object, since `typeof` is so vague and `instanceof` doesn't work cross-window. The behavior of `Object.prototype.toString` (which I assume is what Zambezi means to be using here) is [clearly defined](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.2.4.2) and more useful in many cases than `typeof`. [Here's an example](http://jsbin.com/sehivi) where `instanceof` fails but the above works. Of course, it's unlikely that Zambezi would be working with cross-window regexes. :-)

Comment: while true, also a kind of questionable JS practice of course. Robust cross window (or frame) communication would be a postMessage affair =)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to do the exact same thing that Angular is doing you should be doing it like this:

```
function isRegExp(value) { 
  return Object.prototype.toString.call(value) === '[object RegExp]'; 
}
```

Notice [this section of code](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/14ff529fbbff46413c0cb451a2f0abbd16b05d5e/src/Angular.js#L172) that defines the shortcut `toString`.

Example:

```js
var toString = Object.prototype.toString;
function isRegExp(value) { 
  return toString.call(value) === '[object RegExp]'; 
}
snippet.log(isRegExp(/foo/)); // true
```

```html
<!-- Script provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

The reason for doing this `toString` thing rather than `instanceof` or similar is that the behavior of `Object.prototype.toString` is very well-defined [in the spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.2.4.2), and this technique works even when the `RegExp` object you're testing came from another window, whereas using `instanceof` doesn't work in that case. Here's an example showing that: http://jsbin.com/sehivi

Comment: Can I say Boooya!